How to use setTimeout to prevent server flood when trying to find out whenever an user is typing?
I've been trying to figure out how to do this and it seems that getting the time that has passed from the start of the Timeout event is quite complicated.
I want to send to the server a message whenever an user is typing in an input field. The thing is that I do not want to flood the server with messages whenever the user hits a button so I wanted to optimize the setTimeout calls so that once the timeout has started it shall last for a maximum of five seconds. However instead of resetting the timeout each time a key is pressed, I'd like to have the timeout refreshed only if a button has been pressed less than 0.5 seconds before the old timeout is over.
Everything I saw seems very complicated and I do not know how to adapt that to my code.
If anyone if wondering this is what I did so far:
var myTimeout = null;
$('#messageid').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode != 13) {
    if (myTimeout !== null) {
      // Here is where I should have a conditional statement that would check how long has passed from the timeout event    
      clearTimeout(myTimeout);
      myTimeout = null;
      console.log("User is typing!!!");
      myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);
      var data = {
        userName: "<?php echo $currentuser_name; ?>",
        msg_type: "typing"
      };
      conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
      console.log("User is typing!!!");
      myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);
      var data = {
        userName: "<?php echo $currentuser_name; ?>",
        msg_type: "typing"
      };
      conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }
});


function myGreeting() {
  console.log("User stopped typing!!!");

  var data = {
    userName: "<?php echo $currentuser_name; ?>",
    msg_type: "stopped_typing"
  };
  conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}    

Maybe you can help me adapt something to my code and it may help me actually understand how to handle such things in the future.

The pattern is called 'debouncing'. If you research this term then I'm sure you'll find lots of examples. One of which is in the duplicate I've marked
